# What's more performatic when comparing Strings that you know the length will always be one?

Tags: java, string, performance, equals

I have a String returned from the database that will always have length equals to one.

This String may be equals to "0", "1", "Y", "N" or null, that actually is a constraint in the database that I'm not allowed to replace because of log purposes.

Considering that the values "Y" or "N" are case insensitive, what's more performatic?

```
public boolean isTrue {
    return this.str != null && (this.str.equals("1") || this.str.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
}
```

or

```
public boolean isTrue {
    if (this.str != null) {
        final char character = this.str.charAt(0);
        return character == '1' || character == 'S' || character == 's';
    }
    return false;
}
```

PS: Please, do not consider the name of the methods, fields and variables.

Comment: You can also use this.campoComentarioArea.charAt(0);

Comment: Is _this_ your performance bottleneck? I think not - so don't care about minute differences in performance.

Comment: @JanDvorak Agreed. Code clarity should be top priority here since getting the data from the database will take many orders of magnitude more time than this. OP is trying to optimize a microsecond operation.

Comment: This questions is only for study purposes.

Comment: @GerritCap, that's true. Great observation.

Comment: You can measure performance using simple benchmark like this:

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  
  for(int i=0; i<1000000;++i){
   yourObject.isTrue1();
  }

     long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("Total execution time: " + (endTime-startTime) + "ms");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check my Letter is there in `"01YN"`, I Would do

```
public boolean isTrue {
    return this.str != null && ("01YN".indexOf(this.str)>=0);
}
```

I consider this a clean and readable way. More over you can declare a `Constant`  for `"01YN"` and do, Instead of hard coding here.

Comment: Slight bug, should be `>= 0`.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Yes fixed.

Comment: Great answer, althought here we end up with almost the same doubt since we can do
    public boolean isTrue {
        return this.str != null && ("01YN".indexOf(this.str.charAt(0))>=0);
    }

Answer (score 2):

This might be worth a try:

```
switch(str == null ? 'x' : str.charAt(0)) {
    case '1', 'y', 'Y':
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: this is a nice code, but doesn't actually answers the question about the performance issue. I think you already knows that comparing using chars is more performatic using this approach.